# pay for pending products in Magento

Tags: magento, payment

In Magento, if a payment method (e.g. Paypal) wasn't successfully finished (e.g. the payment gateway wasn't available), the products are marked as pending in the customers order overview.

How is it possible to try paying again later?

Comment: Did you try open this order and generate new invoice?

Comment: I don't want the shop owner to that in the backend, but a button for the customer in the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

order repay extension
[Magento Order Repay Extension](http://www.54dev.com/product/magento-repay)